# Stress test BlazeDS polling

Tags: blazeds, jmeter, amf, stress-testing

I'm looking for some guidance on stress testing BlazeDS **polling** channels.

I've followed this excellent article on using jmeter to test AMF messaging:

http://blog.jteam.nl/2009/07/14/performance-testing-a-flex-blazeds-application/

But that's only suitable for non-polling messages. I can't just generate the AMF for all polling messages upfront - each sequential message varies.

I'm thinking that I may be able to use a BeanShell PreProcessor to create the AMF request java object, then serialize that and send it as POST data.

I'd also need a BeanShell PostProcessor to deserialize the binary AMF response and pass some data to the next request.

Has anyone had a go at something like this before? I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is beyond the capabilities of jmeter's Pre and PostProcessors.

Thanks,
Stu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to say no, this isn't possible with jmeter's pre/post processors.

I've had to abandon jmeter and build my own simple load testing java app, which creates the AMF request objects.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for JMeter that will let you record AMF messages, edit them in XML, then use them in a stress test. You can put variables (e.g. user ids, counters) into the XML that will be replaced when they are delivered. It can also store responses in a JMeter variable for data extraction and re-use in later requests.

http://github.com/steeltomato/jmeter-amf

Full disclosure: I am the project author.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool build by the BlazeDS/LCDS team for stress testing the messaging framework (I suppose that's what you want). Read [this link](http://www.dcooper.org/blog/client/index.cfm?mode=entry&entry=23AFFFB0-4E22-1671-5DE9B407B946CE4D) for further details.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the response. That doens't look suitable for my needs though. Seems to be NIO only and I need more control over the actual messages. Thanks anyway!